# Mostrar frecuencia de caracter en un string

Tags: c#, linq

Nuevamente por aquí, estoy intentando poder imprimir por pantalla la frecuencia relativa del caracter que más veces se encuentra en una cadena. Para poder calcular la frecuencia relativa la fórmula es la siguiente:

```
fr = Cantidad de veces que aparece el caracter / Cantidad total de caracteres de la cadena
```

**CODIGO EN CUESTIÓN:**

```
var resultado = cadena
                .Replace(" ","")
                .OrderBy(c => c).ToArray()
                .GroupBy(c => char.ToUpperInvariant(c))
                .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                .First();


            float frecuencia = resultado.Count() / cadena.Length;



            Console.WriteLine($"CARACTER '{resultado.Key}' SE REPITE {resultado.Count()} VECES Y SU FRECUENCIA ES {frecuencia}");
```

Al correr el código esto es lo que obtengo |

**RESULTADO:**

**ENTRADA:**

> HOLAAA

**SALIDA:**

> CARACTER 'A' SE REPITE TRES VECES Y SU FRECUENCIA ES 0

No logro obtener que se imprima en pantalla su frecuencia (recibo un 0), y tendria que obtener 0.5 (3 apariciones / 6 caracter de longitud).

Espero que me puedan dar una mano, ya probe utilizando Double,Decimal y var pero no logro que haga el cálculo, no se si es problema de calculo o donde estoy metiendo la pata.

Un saludo.

Comment: No soy muy bueno en C, pero si en lugar de `resultado.Count()` usas `resultado.Key`?

Comment: No, ya que resultado.Key devolvera el valor del caracter que más veces se repite, por ejemplo en HOLAAA, devuelve 65 que es su valor ASCII. Y la cuenta quedaría 65 / 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás haciendo la división con 2 enteros, de modo que el resultado es un entero antes de asignarlo a tu `float`, de modo que pierdes la parte fraccional.

Asegurate de convertir los enteros a `float` para no tener este problema:

```
float frecuencia = (float)resultado.Count() / cadena.Length;
```

Comment: Claro, solucionado. Era ese el problema, al realizar la cuenta no se guardaba como punto flotante y me quedaba los decimales en el "aire". Gracias. Te envío flores en esto días :)